# Natural Language Processing for fast detection of nouns

Tags: nlp, spacy

I have long texts from which I need to extract nouns. I use `spaCy` as

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg") # for better name entity detection
doc = nlp(text)
for token in doc:
    if token.tag_=='NN' or token.tag_=='NNP':
        # store token.lemma_
for ent in doc.ents:
    # store ent.text
```

However, it is very slow, as `spaCy` does the full analysis, which I do not need.

can I speed up `spaCy` to do this specific job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed spaCy up by disabling the pretrained pipes that you don't need:

```
with nlp.disable_pipes("tagger", "parser"):
   # your code
```

(note that if you still want to access `token.tag`, you can't disable the `tagger`)

Or you could even avoid loading these components altogether:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg", disable=["tagger", "parser"])
```

Even only disabling the `parser` should definitely give you a speed boost.

For more information, see [here](https://spacy.io/api/language#disable_pipes).